# Button not responding (even not hover)

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
const sentence = document.getElementById('sentence')
const word = document.getElementById('word')
const number = document.getElementById('number')

const btnContainer = document.getElementById('btnContainer')


function Start() {
  btnContainer.style.display = 'flex';
}

Start()

sentence.addEventListener('click', () => {
  type = 1;
  Start();
})
word.addEventListener('click', () => {
  type = 2;
  Start();
})
number.addEventListener('click', () => {
  type = 3;
  Start();
})
```

```css
.btnContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  right: .5vw;
  gap: .2em;
  width: 25vw;
  height: 10vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.btn {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: transparent;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  color: var(--lightprimary);
  transition: ease-in-out .2s;
}

.btn:hover {
  color: var(--darkprimary);
}
```

```html
<div class="btnContainer" id="btnContainer">
  <button class="sentenceButton btn" id="sentence">Sentence</button>
  <button class="wordButton btn" id="word">Words</button>
  <button class="numberButton btn" id="number">Numbers</button>
</div>
```

There is more code that hasn't something to do with the buttons.
The 'btnContainer.style.display' is necessary to work with the other code.

Comment: can you add the code as a runnable sick of coping code around

Comment: Are `--darkprimary` and `--lightprimary` defined in your original code? That would solve the hover part.

Comment: Define the variables and they should work. It works, I tried.

Comment: `--darkprimary` and `--lightprimary` are defined as `:root`

Comment: You have declared too many properties as transparent, that's why hover is not visible.

Comment: @Youri_Miner can you add your `:root` CSS to see if it is grabbing it properly?

Comment: Currently the clicks are not doing anything notable in your code. Add some `console.log()`s to the click handlers and see if they are responding. Also `Start()` is already called so button clicks won't do anything further.

Comment: @Azu, No, hover is not visible because there must be issues in `:root` CSS, it works correctly if you replace the two `color` properties by direct values.

Comment: i did that but it didn't do anything @aerial301

Comment: Alright I found the problem from the full code you posted in answers. Just add `z-index: 999;` to your `.btn` class. This will fix those 3 buttons on the top right and make them clickable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const shortApi = 'https://api.quotable.io/random?minLength=60&maxLength=80'
const mediumApi = 'https://api.quotable.io/random?minLength=100&maxLength=180'
const longApi = 'https://api.quotable.io/random?minLength=200&maxLength=220'

const display = document.getElementById('display')
const input = document.getElementById('input')
const restart = document.getElementById('restart-btn')

const sentence = document.getElementById('sentence')
const word = document.getElementById('word')
const number = document.getElementById('number')

const actionBtn1 = document.getElementById('btn1')
const actionBtn2 = document.getElementById('btn2')
const actionBtn3 = document.getElementById('btn3')
const actionBtn4 = document.getElementById('btn4')

const container = document.getElementById('container')
const btnContainer = document.getElementById('btnContainer')
const smallBtnContainer = document.getElementById('smallBtnContainer')

const stats = document.getElementById('stats')

const exit = document.getElementById('exit')

var type = 1
async function newQuote() {
  display.innerText = '';
  var quote = 'hello world'

  let arr = quote.split("").map(value => {
    return "<span class='span'>" + value + "</span>"
  })

  display.innerHTML += arr.join("");
}

function Start() {
  newQuote()

  input.value = null

  stats.style.display = 'none';
  container.style.display = 'flex';
  btnContainer.style.display = 'flex';
  smallBtnContainer.style.display = 'block';

  input.disabled = false;

  let startTime = null
  let endTime = null

  input.addEventListener('input', () => {

    if (startTime == null)
      startTime = new Date()

    let quoteChars = document.querySelectorAll(".span")

    var mistakes = 0

    quoteChars = Array.from(quoteChars)

    let inputChars = input.value.split("")

    quoteChars.forEach((char, index) => {
      if (char.innerText === inputChars[index]) {
        char.classList.add('correct')
        char.classList.remove('incorrect')
      } else if (inputChars[index] == null) {
        char.classList.remove('correct')
        char.classList.remove('incorrect')
      } else {
        char.classList.remove('correct')
        char.classList.add('incorrect')
        mistakes += 1
      }
    })

    if (inputChars.length >= quoteChars.length) {
      clicked = false

      stats.style.display = 'block';
      container.style.display = 'none';
      btnContainer.style.display = 'none';
      smallBtnContainer.style.display = 'none';

      input.disabled = true;
      endTime = new Date()

      const delta = endTime - startTime
      const seconds = delta / 1000
      const minutes = seconds / 60
      const accuracy = Math.round(((input.value.length - mistakes) / input.value.length) * 100)
      const wpm = (input.value.length / 5 / minutes).toFixed(2) + " wpm"
      document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = wpm
      document.getElementById('mistakes').innerText = mistakes
      document.getElementById('accuracy').innerText = accuracy + "%"
    }

  })
}

function changeActionButtons(type) {
  actionBtn1.style.display = 'block'
  actionBtn2.style.display = 'block'
  actionBtn3.style.display = 'block'
  actionBtn4.style.display = 'block'
  if (type == 1) {
    actionBtn1.style.display = 'none'
    actionBtn2.textContent = 'short'
    actionBtn3.textContent = 'medium'
    actionBtn4.textContent = 'long'
  } else if (type == 2) {
    actionBtn1.textContent = '1'
    actionBtn2.textContent = '10'
    actionBtn3.textContent = '20'
    actionBtn4.textContent = '30'
  } else if (type == 3) {
    actionBtn1.textContent = '1'
    actionBtn2.textContent = '5'
    actionBtn3.textContent = '10'
    actionBtn4.textContent = '15'
  }
}

changeActionButtons(type)
Start()

exit.addEventListener('click', () => {
  stats.style.display = 'none';
  container.style.display = 'flex';
  btnContainer.style.display = 'block';
  smallBtnContainer.style.display = 'block';
  Start()
})

restart.addEventListener('click', () => {
  Start();
})

sentence.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('gello');
  type = 1;
  changeActionButtons(1);
  Start();
  console.log('clicked');
})
word.addEventListener('click', () => {
  type = 2;
  changeActionButtons(2);
  Start();
})
number.addEventListener('click', () => {
  type = 3;
  changeActionButtons(3);
  Start();
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 :root {
  --primary: #222;
  --lightprimary: #555;
  --darkprimary: #0f0f0f;
  --secondary: #ffcf00;
  --incorrect: #ff2d2d;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: var(--primary);
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: 'Oxygen', Arial, sans-serif;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
}

button {
  font-family: 'Oxygen', Arial, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 90%;
  height: 50vh;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  color: var(--lightprimary);
  max-width: 1000px;
  transition: ease-in-out .2s;
}

.quote {
  font-family: 'Oxygen Mono', monospace;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
}

.input {
  font-family: 'Oxygen Mono', monospace;
  position: absolute;
  top: 280px;
  resize: none;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid var(--lightprimary);
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  margin: auto;
  outline: none;
  text-align: center;
  color: var(--lightprimary);
  background-color: transparent;
}

.input:focus {
  border-color: var(--darkprimary);
}

.restart-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 340px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: transparent;
  font-size: 4rem;
  color: var(--lightprimary);
  transition: ease-in-out .2s;
}

.restart-btn:hover {
  color: var(--darkprimary);
}

.btnContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  right: .5vw;
  gap: .2em;
  width: 25vw;
  height: 10vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.btn {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  color: var(--lightprimary);
  transition: ease-in-out .2s;
}

.btn:hover {
  color: var(--darkprimary);
}

.smallBtnContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  right: 6.5vw;
  gap: .2em;
  width: 25vw;
  height: 10vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.smallBtn {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: transparent;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: var(--lightprimary);
  transition: ease-in-out .2s;
}

.smallBtn:hover {
  color: var(--darkprimary);
}

.stats {
  display: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 40vw;
  height: 40vh;
  position: absolute;
  color: var(--secondary);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  transition: ease-in-out .2s;
}

.exit {
  font-size: 2rem;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: transparent;
  color: var(--lightprimary);
  transition: ease-in-out .2s;
}

.exit:hover {
  color: var(--darkprimary);
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.title {
  position: absolute;
  color: var(--secondary);
  top: 75px;
  left: 150px;
}

.correct {
  color: var(--secondary);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.incorrect {
  color: var(--incorrect);
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oxygen&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oxygen+Mono&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Type Lite</title>
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <img class="logo" alt='logo'>
  <p class='title'>logo</p>

  <div class="stats" id="stats">
    <p>Score: <span id="score"></span></p>
    <p>Mistakes: <span id="mistakes"></span></p>
    <p>Accuracy: <span id="accuracy"></span></p>
    <button class="exit" id="exit">X</button>
  </div>
  <div class="container" id="container">
    <div class="quote" id="display"></div>
    <textarea class="input" id="input" cols="90" rows="2" placeholder="Type here to start." autofocus></textarea>
    <button class="restart-btn" id="restart-btn">Restart</button>
  </div>
  <div class="btnContainer" id="btnContainer">
    <button class="sentenceButton btn" id="sentence">Sentence</button>
    <button class="wordButton btn" id="word">Words</button>
    <button class="numberButton btn" id="number">Numbers</button>
  </div>
  <div class="smallBtnContainer" id="smallBtnContainer">
    <button class="smallBtn" id="btn1">1</button>
    <button class="smallBtn" id="btn2">2</button>
    <button class="smallBtn" id="btn3">3</button>
    <button class="smallBtn" id="btn4">4</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Apparently here its working

Comment: Yes, the issue is you have to define color in your `:root` please see my answer for clarification. If you add `-color` to the end of each of your `:root` styles this should be solved.

Comment: @Youri_Miner Buttons work here in the small snippet window because the div with the id `smallBtnContainer` is not fully covering the buttons while in big window size it covers them and they can't be hovered or clicked. So giving the buttons some high z-index would solve the issue

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @aerial301 That makes alot of sense... And i have done what you said and it fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm that your CSS `:root` selector is structured like so. In order for it to grab the primary color, you have to define that color first. Also, as mentioned in the comments it appears your buttons are responding via the console log.

```js
const sentence = document.getElementById('sentence')
const word = document.getElementById('word')
const number = document.getElementById('number')

const btnContainer = document.getElementById('btnContainer')


function Start() {
    btnContainer.style.display = 'flex';
}

Start()

sentence.addEventListener('click', () => { type = 1; Start(); })
word.addEventListener('click', () => { type = 2; Start(); })
number.addEventListener('click', () => { type = 3; Start(); })
```

```css
.btnContainer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    right: .5vw;
    gap: .2em;
    width: 25vw;
    height: 10vh;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.btn {
    background-color: white;
    border: hidden;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    color: var(--lightprimary);
    transition: ease-in-out .2s;
}

.btn:hover {
    background-color: var(--darkprimary-color);
}

:root {
  --darkprimary-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="btnContainer" id="btnContainer">
 <button class="sentenceButton btn" id="sentence" type="button">Sentence</button>
 <button class="wordButton btn" id="word" type="button">Words</button>
 <button class="numberButton btn" id="number" type="button">Numbers</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without the Javascript code and with defined `--lightprimary` and `--darkprimary`, everything works.

```css
:root{
    --lightprimary: green;
    --darkprimary: red;
    
}
.btnContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  right: .5vw;
  gap: .2em;
  width: 25vw;
  height: 10vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.btn {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: transparent;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  color: var(--lightprimary);
  transition: ease-in-out .2s;
}

.btn:hover {
  color: var(--darkprimary);
}
```

```html
<div class="btnContainer" id="btnContainer">
  <button class="sentenceButton btn" id="sentence">Sentence</button>
  <button class="wordButton btn" id="word">Words</button>
  <button class="numberButton btn" id="number">Numbers</button>
</div>
```